# Use match case to handle exceptions

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a method that receives an exception of type Exception as a parameter and I want to filter which exceptions to show to the user and which to show as general errors.

Since I have more than 10 of these exceptions in the real code, I wanted to use a match case that filters out the different cases.

I only want to match the type of exceptions and I don't want to use an if elif for each exception if possible, as code inside each if would be the same.

```py
def handle_exception(self, exception: Exception):
    # Built the error message, based on which exception was caught
    match exception:
        case MyCustomExceptionOne() \
             | MyCustomExceptionTwo() \
             | MyCustomExceptionThree():
            show_error_message(exception) 
        case _:
            show_error_message("Error occured")
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Since this code isn't runnable, what exactly "does not work" here? Why are you trying to use `match` `case` to begin with instead of a simple `if isinstance`? For that matter, why does this code handle the exception by *receiving* it instead of *catching* it via `except` (which already does `if isinstance` under the hood)?

Comment: "does not work as I thought it would" is not a sufficient problem description. What behavior are you seeing, and what did you expect to happen instead? Can you post a [mcve]?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify what you are asking. Are you wondering why `match` `case` fails in a specific way here? Are you trying to *structurally* match some exceptions and it does not work? If so please provide a [mre].  Are you looking for *general* how-to of branching on exceptions? If so please clearly ask for that and also consider to clarify whether you just need to match the *type* or also value/structure of the exception, as the use of `match` `case` implies.

Comment: Why have you used slashes between the ‘or’ operators( |)?

Comment: @Dinux It's a line continuation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need nor advantage for `case` `match` just to match multiple types: An `if` can efficiently match on multiple types using `if isinstance(obj, (type1, type2, ...))`.

```
def handle_exception(self, exception: Exception):
    # Built the error message, based on which exception was caught
    if isinstance(
        exception,
        (MyCustomExceptionOne, MyCustomExceptionTwo, MyCustomExceptionThree)
    ):
        show_error_message(exception) 
    else:
        show_error_message("Error occured")
```

This is equivalent to what `except (type1, type2, ...):` does under the hood, thus matching the usual exception handling semantics.

Note that the second argument to `isinstance` is a regular `tuple` here. If code clarity is an issue, it can be defined elsewhere and simply referenced:

```
MY_EXCEPTIONS = (MyCustomExceptionOne, MyCustomExceptionTwo, MyCustomExceptionThree)

def handle_exception(self, exception: Exception):
    # Built the error message, based on which exception was caught
    if isinstance(exception, MY_EXCEPTIONS):
        show_error_message(exception) 
    else:
        show_error_message("Error occured")
```